# CPU emulator in Java

Tags: java, object-oriented, virtual-machine

I recently started new project - a CPU emulator in Java.
Base code is written, now I can start to slowly implement new things, but I want code review to be done, to reformat code before it messes up.
Unfortunately, I didn't add any Javadocs and didn't do any deeper tests, except checking if basic OP codes are working.

[https://github.com/jakub-gonet/Emulated-CPU](https://github.com/jakub-gonet/Emulated-CPU/tree/c01e0ca863fd5b718d67675996be2bb669a66514)

Code structure is like so:

- CommandHelper.py - script used to convert Op code to binary form and vice versa
- Main - entry point
- **cpu/OPCODE - list of OP codes and what they should do**
- cpu/ADDR_TYPE - addressing modes
- cpu/StatusFlags - CPU flags (carry, negative, zero flag etc)
- cpu/programCounter - program counter
- **cpu/CPUEmulator - main class to bind rest to it**
- cpu/instructionArgument, InstructionMnemonic, Instruction - used to encode a single instruction
- **cpu/instruction/InstructionRunner - fetch and run Instruction**
- cpu/instruction/converter - package used to convert from bits to OP code and address modes
- cpu/memory - package used to represent CPU memory

(bolded are important)

```
package cpu.instruction;

import cpu.ADDR_TYPE;
import cpu.instruction.converter.ValueToAddressingMode;
import cpu.instruction.converter.ValueToOPCode;
import cpu.memory.Memory;

public class InstructionRunner {
    public static void run(Instruction instruction) {
        if (instruction != null) {
            Integer arg2Value = (instruction.getArg2() != null) ? instruction.getArg2()
                                                                             .getValue() : null;

            Integer arg1Value = (instruction.getArg1() != null) ? instruction.getArg1()
                                                                             .getValue() : null;

            Integer address = (instruction.getArg1() != null) ? instruction.getArg1()
                                                                           .getAddress() : null;

            Integer value = instruction.getMnemonic()
                                       .getOpcode()
                                       .apply(arg1Value,
                                           arg2Value);

            if (instruction.getArgumentCount() > 0) instruction.getArg1()
                                                               .getMemory()
                                                               .write(address, value);
        } else throw new
            IllegalArgumentException("ERROR: Instruction can't be null.");

    }

    public static Instruction fetchInstruction(int address) {
        try {
            int opCodeAndAddresses = readFromMemory(address);
            InstructionMnemonic mnemonic = new InstructionMnemonic(
                ValueToOPCode.getOPCode(opCodeAndAddresses)
            );
            InstructionArgument[] arguments = createArguments(mnemonic.getRequiredArgs(), address, opCodeAndAddresses);

            return new Instruction(mnemonic, arguments[0], arguments[1]);

        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: OP code not recognized.");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Bad format of instruction.");
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static InstructionArgument[] createArguments(int argumentCount, int address, int argumentsCode) {
        InstructionArgument arg2 = null;
        InstructionArgument arg1 = null;

        switch (argumentCount) {
            case 2:
                int arg2Code = readFromMemory(address + 2);
                ADDR_TYPE secondAddressType = getAddressType(2, argumentsCode);
                arg2 = new InstructionArgument(arg2Code, secondAddressType);
            case 1:
                int arg1Code = readFromMemory(address + 1);
                ADDR_TYPE firstAddressType = getAddressType(1, argumentsCode);
                arg1 = new InstructionArgument(arg1Code, firstAddressType);
        }
        return new InstructionArgument[] {arg1, arg2};
    }

    private static ADDR_TYPE getAddressType(int argumentNumber, int operatorAndAddressingModeCode) {
        if (argumentNumber == 1) return ValueToAddressingMode.getFirstArgAddressingMode(operatorAndAddressingModeCode);
        if (argumentNumber == 2) return ValueToAddressingMode.getSecondArgAddressingMode(operatorAndAddressingModeCode);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("ERROR: OP code argument does not exist.");
    }

    private static int readFromMemory(int address) {
        return Memory.getInstance()
                     .read(address);
    }
}
```

I mostly wonder if that null policy is good practice and how to manage exceptions in that type of project.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. I hope you get great answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your code.

> I mostly wonder if that null policy is good practice

The answer is No. Checking for `null` is not a good practice.

In Your case you need the null check (in the code you posted) because your code violates the most important OO principle: *information hiding / encapsulation*. And this is accompanied by violating the *feature envy* code smell.

The `InstructionRunner` class should not know about the internals of an `Instruction`. From the point of the  `InstructionRunner` an Instruction should have an execute method that returns the new value for the *instruction pointer*. This execute method should get the current value of  the *instruction pointer*, the "memory" (which is merely a list of bytes) and an object representing the ALU to be modified by the instruction.

So I'd write the code you presented this way:

```
   /* this is a pure data structure so public members are OK */
   class ArithmeticLogicUnit{
     public int accumulator=0;
     public int a=0; // register A
     public int b=0; // register B
     public int d=0; // register D
     public int e=0; // register E
     public int h=0; // register H
     public int l=0; // register L
   } 

   interface InstructionPool{
     //* convert byte(s)in memory at/from  instructionPointer to Instruction */
     Instruction decode(int instructionPointer,  List<Integer> memory);
   } 

   interface Instruction{
     //* modify the ALU and calculate the next value of <code>instructionPointer</code>*/
     int execute(int instructionPointer,  List<Integer> memory, ArithmeticLogicUnit alu);
   }

   class ControlUnit{
      private final ArithmeticLogicUnit alu = new ArithmeticLogicUnit();
      private final InstructionPool instructionPool;
      private final List<Integer> memory;
      private int instructionPointer;
      public ComtrolUnit(int initialInstructionPointer, List<Integer>  memory, InstructionPool instructionPool){
          this.memory = memory;
          this.instructionPool = instructionPool;
      }         
      public void run(int initialInstructionPointer){          
          this.instructionPointer = initialInstructionPointer;
          while(instructionPointer >= 0 && instructionPointer < memory.size()){
             Instruction instruction = instructionPool.decode(instructionPointer, memory);
             instructionPointer = instruction.execute(instructionPointer,  memory, alu);
          }
      }
    }
```

> and how to manage exceptions in that type of project.

Exceptions should be handled the way as you do in any other project: Use them to interrupt the "happy day path". Use *checked exceptions* if you expect the calling code to recover from that error anyhow (including asking the user what to do) and use *unchecked exceptions* if you think the program (or at least the current thread) as a whole cannot run any longer reliably.
`

Comment: Should I merge ALU and registers into one thing or separate them?

Comment: @Jump3r In real life the ALU *has* the registers. So its "one thing" as I wrote it.